# activity and/or service

Tags: android

I have an activity and a service component in my application.

The intention is to let the service take care of preparing the `SurfaceView` and mediaplayer instance that needs a surface holder. My media is a video file.

Is it possible to create the surface view from within my service?

Can I call the following

`surface = (MySurfaceView) findViewById(R.id.surface);`

in my service component?

If I did that, i could then assign the `surface.getHolder` to the player instance's `setDisplay()`.

The overall goal is to issue commands (play, stop, seek, etc) from the activity and have the service implement the control of the mediaplayer state.

I probably could put all the stuff in my activity, but when i rotate the device, i don't want to tear down the surface and recreate it in `onConfigurationChanged()`. Hence looking at using the service for my situation here.

Any ideas or solutions highly appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You could use an `AsyncTask` implementation instead of the service, and do

- all the background work in its
  `doInBackground` method (different
  thread, won't bother the user
  interface), while
- all the UI-related work could be done
  in the `onPostExecute` method (the UI
  thread).

**Update**
Since you need your media to be played in a background thread (without possible interruptions by gui processes), the `Service` could be a choice for you. You'll also need an `Activity` though, to start, stop and control your service. 
For how to implement this design, you can check out this [MusicDroid Tutorial part 2](http://www.helloandroid.com/tutorials/musicdroid-audio-player-part-ii).

Though, it's not mandatory, to use services for this task, @CommonsWare's solution is very elegant and handy.
[@CommonsWare's streaming video test application](https://github.com/commonsguy/vidtry/tree), and this [Audio/Video player sample](http://davanum.wordpress.com/2009/12/04/android-%E2%80%93-videomusic-player-sample-take-2/) don't use services.

Comment: I don't see how AsyncTask could help me. The mediaplayer should be running in the background during the entire life of the application.

Comment: MediaPlayer will playback audio only, if surface is not availabale. I'm not sure if you can attach/detach/re-attach surface on the fly, but playback should be working fine without surface. This means that you can put your player inside service, while surface will be managed by activity.

Comment: I've added some useful links to posts -with samples- that walk you through different implementations of this task.

Comment: Hi inazaruk, That is my problem precisely - the player in the service needs a surface BUT the surface is managed by the activity. How to connect the two? Can i pass the surface view object to the service component (via Intent's putExtra) while calling the startService()? If yes, can you point me how do send an object in the intent? I have only used it for sending Strings and ints and some other primitive types.

Comment: Hi rekaszeru, I am looking at your links. Let me see if anything meets my needs. Thanks for taking time to post the links here.

Comment: Hi rekaszeru, The implementation examples don't use the service at all. All of them use the current activity. So, if the activity is off the stack, then the player stops. I am pretty convinced i need the service for my needs - something that runs in the background without user intervention. Only thing i am not able to figure out is how to associate a surface created in the activity to the player instance created in the service. Thanks.

Comment: The first link (from musicdroid site) does use service for this task. And you could use shared Handler, service binding, broadcasts, to realize communication between the ui and your service.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to start and stop `Service` from the `Activity`, try using the approach described [in this example application](http://marakana.com/forums/android/examples/60.html). It worked for me.

The demo could be even [downloaded](http://marakana.com/static/tutorials/ServicesDemo.zip). You will need [this music file](http://marakana.com/static/tutorials/braincandy.m4a).